# Is it possible to generate an arbitrary surface, which maps an image onto a point with any distortion we please?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to write a function (even a discrete, iterative one) that can generate a surface S, which will take an incoming light field of vectors V, and map it onto a point Q (which is a camera).

This seems possible if we define some initial conditions, but, I'm not sure how to go about it.

A drawing of the problem at hand:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely but conic sections have such reflective properties. Any light ray emanating from one focus of an ellipse (or ellipsoid) will be refocused onto the other focus. A parabolic surface of revolution reflects incoming parallel rays towards its focus. That's the basis of radio telescopes and your TV satellite dish, for instance.